# pass along the field and value while aggregating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I had an output document from a pipeline something like : `{upvotes : 1, downvotes : 5}`. I just wanted to pass that along to the next part of the pipeline. I did something like this:

```
{
    $group :{
        _id : "$_id",
        upvotes : {$max : "$upvotes"},
        downvotes : {$max : "$downvotes"},
        average : {$avg : "$statements.result"},
        count : {$max : "$count"}
    }
}
```

I didn't want to use max I don't want the maximum of anything. I just wanted the field and value: `{upvotes : 1, downvotes : 5}`. lets say they were not numbers. lets say the fields were object I want all the objects for that field to be outputted not the max.

make this question clearer: how can I get the the field and value without using `max`?

outputs:

```
[ { _id: 57aea6791016c0b023a71e9d,
    upvotes: 3,
    downvotes: 1,
    average: 7.857142857142857,
    count: 5 },
  { _id: 57aed883139c1e702beb471e,
    upvotes: 0,
    downvotes: 1,
    average: 7,
    count: 1 } ]
```

The output is good but I don't want to use max to get it.

For some reason I think I need an [Accumulator Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator). That is why I use `max`.

Comment: Cant see a clear question here?

Comment: what part is unclear?

Comment: I am still trying to parse the language after the code block. Hurting my head a bit. Are you not just looking for `$group.upvotes` or one of the other fields since it won't have max but the other objects(one with upvotes, downvots)?

Comment: When using $group you can make a field and I wanted the value of that field to be the value of the field from the previous output of a pipeline. In my case the two fields have the same name. `{upvotes : 1, downvotes : 5}` was the output from the previous step of the pipeline. I wanted `{upvotes : 1, downvotes : 5}` to be in the next output. a trick was to use `max`. what other way is there?

Comment: For some reason I think I need an Accumulator Operator. That is why I use max. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group

Answer (score 0):

Since you are grouping by "$_id", you're actually not grouping at all.  Your results are going to correlate 1:1 to your initial data set.  To accomplish what you are asking, passing along upvotes and downvotes without using an aggregate function like $max, you'd just include them in the _id for your group stage which is where you specify your group by key.

So you would do:

```
{
    $group :{
        _id : {
            "_id":"$_id",
            "upvotes": "$upvotes",
            "downvotes": "$downvotes"
        }
        average : {$avg : "$statements.result"},
        count : {$max : "$count"}
    }
}
```

But still, you are going to end up with a 1:1 correlation to your original data.

Answer (score 0):

Following your question thread, your pipeline in question is most probably a preceding pipeline step from an **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operation thence the following suggested solution is based on that assumption. Please feel free to suggest otherwise.

To include a field in the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline using the accumulators, the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** seem most appropriate here since you have just flattened an array and those operators will return a value from the first/last document for each group. What is means is if the field is not part of a flattened array then **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)**/**[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** would give you its actual value before the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** took place.

```
{
    "$group" :{
        "_id": "$_id",
        "upvotes": { "$first": "$upvotes"},
        "downvotes": { "$first": "$downvotes"},
        "average": { "$avg": "$statements.result"},
        "count": { "$max": "$count"}
    }
}
```